# R package selective import and namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

My question is: How do I selectively import functions from two packages in the case where two of the packages have functions named DanielPlot (which is one of the functions I wish to import). I would like to import the DanielPlot function from the FrF2 package, but the BsMD package also has a function called DanielPlot. I tried selectively importing the functions I want from each package, but it does not work. A portion of my DESCRIPTION file is below:

```
Depends: 
         lattice

Imports: FrF2, 

         BsMD
```

and a portion of my NAMESPACE file is:

```
import(lattice)
importFrom(FrF2,DanielPlot)    
importFrom(FrF2, IAPlot)    
importFrom(FrF2, MEPlot)    
importFrom(FrF2, pb)    
importFrom(FrF2, FrF2)    
importFrom(BsMD, BsProb)    
importFrom(BsMD, LenthPlot)    
importFrom(BsMD, BsMD)
```

When I try to check the package I get the message

> Warning messages:
>   replacing previous import by ‘BsMD::DanielPlot’ when loading ‘daewr’

How can I avoid this warning?

Comment: Are they exactly the same function?  If not, you can use the `::` operator in your functions that use `DanielPlot` and not need to specify the function name with `importFrom`, and just use `import`

Comment: Unless you also have some `library()` or `require()` calls, this seems to be a bug to me. But the workaround by @RichardScriven should work.